# What happened to all the other Alice clones?

Tags: clones, resident-evil

Here's a question that bugs both me and my wife - it comes up every time we watch the RE movies. Sorry for spoiler(ish) title, but there's really no way to describe the topic without revealing that there are Alice clones. Potential major spoilers for those who haven't seen the movies in question, however:

> At the end of Resident Evil 3, when Alice infiltrates the Las Vegas compound, she finds hundreds (if not thousands) of Alice clones, leading us to question if she is even the original Alice or merely one of the clones. The end is somewhat ambiguous, but we are left with the impression that she IS the original, and now she has an army of Alices (Alici?) to come after Umbrella Corporation with.

But, then in Resident Evil 4:

> Alice and a handful of her clones (4-6, perhaps) attack the Tokyo facility. During the attack, a few of the clones get killed while a few more are blown up with the facility. No further mention is ever made of the clones or the fact that there is an army of Alices.

So, based on that, here is the question:

> What happened to all the other Alice clones? Are they still curled up in their bubbles back in Las Vegas?

I'd prefer if the accepted answer could include any references from the movies themselves, or a novelization... or even an interview with the cast & crew.

Comment: I have nothing to back this up, but I always assumed that most didn't get out of the cloning facility, and those that did were sent on various missions with/without the "real" Alice. Since Alice/clones no longer have special powers, they've just dwindled in number over time.

Comment: Phew, it looks like I've saved your marriage. I can imagine the arguments going on well into the night on this...

Comment: What disturbs me about the plot is that, even though the clones are not the original Alice, they are still human beings. Why are they sacrificed like that? The idea is that the original Alice is important, the clones are expendable. Feels rather awkward.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [original Screenplay](http://screenplayexplorer.com/wp-content/scripts/Resident-Evi%20-Afterlife.pdf) for "Resident Evil : Afterlife" makes it clear that there were 'dozens' of clones killed in the original assault and more than 30-40 killed by the bomb detonated at the end of the attack, a grand total of 70+ clone deaths.

On top of that, we're told later in the film that the Alice clones have already attacked several other Umbrella facilities, presumably employing the same haphazard "we don't give a damn about casualties" attitude.

> A satellite view of Shibuya appears on the main screen. We see the
>   battle above played out in ghostly silence. **Dozens of unidentified
>   INTRUDERS are fighting** with the Umbrella Troops.
>
> **TECHNICIAN :** *Our men are being overrun. Multiple Intruders.*
>
> **WESKER :** *Blow the surface charges.*
>
> suddenly --
>
> **TECHNICIAN 1 :** *Movement*
>
> **TECHNICIAN 2 :** *Multiple targets.*
>
> **WESKER :** *How many?*
>
> The satellite image shows ghostly figures emerging from the buildings
>   of Shibuya.
>   **TECHNICIAN :** ***Twenty ... thirty ... more.***

Regarding the question; "***What happened to all the other Alice clones***?" the reality is that whilst the impression you're given at the end of "Resident Evil: Extinction" is that there are *hundreds* of clones at the Las Vegas facility (the size of the room and mirrored floor making it difficult to confirm exact numbers) the [Original screenplay](http://screenplayexplorer.com/?tag=resident-evil-extinction-script) confirms that there are only 100 clones, so at most we're only left trying to account for a couple of dozen (expendable) footsoldiers.

[image: Alice Clones]

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Il just go by the movies and what I saw only. It seemed there were probably a dozen or 2 clones that attacked the Tokyo facility going by how much damage the 3 we saw did. A lot of them probably died in the attack and 6-9 probably died in the base explosion.

In the final chapter I’m pretty sure it showed clone heads that were hunted down by clone Isaacs so Umbrella was obviously hunting them the whole time but who knows if any were still alive at the end or not?

Also I’m not sure why just because ‘original’ Alice lost her powers that her clones that were already brought into existence also lost their powers. It simply seemed like a way to end the world faster with the power of plot.

Comment: You could improve this answer by editing it to include some evidence, such as screenshots of the things you've referred to. You should probably delete the last paragraph as well, since it does nothing to help answer the question. You could post it as a comment directly beneath your answer.

Answer (score -1):

Presumably they attacked other facilities. As one other incorrectly stated, the alice clones do indeed have some of original alice’s abilities( meaning telekinesis) probably varying in strength. Going back to the very first scene with the elevator.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Do you have any evidence for this theory?  Please try to provide sources that back up your answer.